# Updating data in Clickhouse

Tags: database, clickhouse

I went over the documentation for Clickhouse and I did not see the option to UPDATE nor DELETE. It seems to me its an append only system.
Is there a possibility to update existing records or is there some workaround like truncating a partition that has records in it that have changed and then re-insering the entire data for that partition?

Answer (score 22):

Through Alter query in clickhouse we can able to delete/update the rows in a table.

**For delete**: Query should be constructed as

```
ALTER TABLE testing.Employee DELETE  WHERE  Emp_Name='user4';
```

**For Update**: Query should be constructed as

```
ALTER TABLE testing.employee UPDATE AssignedUser='sunil' where AssignedUser='sunny';
```

Answer (score 19):

UPDATE: This answer is no longer true, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55298764/3583139

ClickHouse doesn't support real UPDATE/DELETE.
But there are few possible workarounds:

1. Trying to organize data in a way, that is need not to be updated.
   You could write log of update events to a table, and then calculate reports from that log. So, instead of updating existing records, you append new records to a table.
2. Using table engine that do data transformation in background during merges. For example, (rather specific) CollapsingMergeTree table engine:
   https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html#CollapsingMergeTree
   Also there are ReplacingMergeTree table engine (not documented yet, you could find example in tests: https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/tests/queries/0_stateless/00325_replacing_merge_tree.sql)
   Drawback is that you don't know, when background merge will be done, and will it ever be done.

Also look at samdoj's answer.

Comment: from `1.1.54388` release 2018-06-28 you can mutate data.
https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/changelog/#clickhouse-release-1-1-54388-2018-06-28

Answer (score 5):

You can drop and create new tables, but depending on their size this might be very time consuming.  You could do something like this:

For deletion, something like this could work.

```
  INSERT INTO tableTemp SELECT * from table1 WHERE  rowID != @targetRowID;
    DROP table1;
    INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * from tableTemp;
```

Similarly, to update a row, you could first delete it in this manner, and then add it.

Comment: But how would I update a very large table. For example, what if my process was to gather a lot of records, then "correct" 15% of them?

Comment: Basically just update and delete multiple rows?  You could first select those rows into a temp table and just change the where clause to be `WHERE rowID is not in (SELECT rowID FROM targetTable`)  You are only limited here by what you can select.

Comment: It would be much more efficient to rename table instead of doing `INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * from tableTemp;`

Answer (score 5):

Functionality to UPDATE or DELETE data has been added in recent ClickHouse releases, but its expensive batch operation which can't be performed too frequently.

See https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/alter/#mutations for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, but updates are now supported in Clickhouse. Note it's not recommended to do many small changes for performance reasons. But it is possible.

**Syntax:**

```
ALTER TABLE [db.]table UPDATE column1 = expr1 [, ...] WHERE filter_expr
```

[Clickhouse UPDATE documentation](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/update/)

Answer (score 0):

To update values you can use the [`ReplacingMergeTree` engine](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree#replacingmergetree).

Having this engine on a table, if you try to append a row with the sort keys that already exists in the table, it will replace previous record that have the same sort keys (like upsert).